# list add&remove method

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I'm trying to do a method which remove the middle element from list of integer but using recursion , i feel really confused about how to do the base case. when i tried this code the input was [1,3,5]
output became[3,5].

````
public static void removeMid(ArrayList<Integer> o){
int i=0;
    int low=0;
    int high=o.size()-1;
    int mid=(high+low)/2;
    
    
    if(o.get(i)!=mid)
    return ;
        else if(o.get(i)==mid) {
            o.remove(i);
    System.out.println(o.get(i)); //return mid element
        
    System.out.println(o);
    removeMid(o);
        }}```
````

Comment: `o.get(i)!=mid` here you compare an index with a list value. This does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the definition what is a *middle element*

Assuming that the middle element is the one placed at the middle index, you should use `List/ArrayList`'s method [`E remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-).

You may want to restrict removal to the case when the size of the input list is odd.

```java
public static void removeMid(ArrayList<Integer> o) {
    if (o.size() > 1 && o.size() % 2 != 0) {
        int removed = o.remove(o.size() / 2);
        System.out.println("removed element: " + removed);
    } else {
        System.out.println("no middle element to remove is available");
    }
}
```

If you need to remove a *middle value*, you may sort the input list and then remove an element at the middle index as before:

```java
public static void removeMidValue(ArrayList<Integer> o) {
    Collections.sort(o);
    removeMid(o);
}
```

**Update**
Recursive solution consists in finding `min` and `max` elements, removing them, calling recursively to remove a mid value from the remaining list, and restoring `min` and `max` values upon returning from the recursive call.  The exit condition from the recursion is when the remaining list contains only one element to be removed.

Another point to address is how to restore the `min` and `max` elements - there are options to use their *indexes* when removing/restoring the element, or just to add `min` and `max` values back to the list thus changing initial order.

That being said, the recursive solution keeping the order may be as follows:

```java
public static void removeMidRecursive(ArrayList<Integer> o) {
    System.out.println("recursive: " + o);
    if (o.size() % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("list size is even, no middle element to remove");
    } else if (o.size() == 1) {
        int mid = o.remove(0);
        System.out.println("removed mid element: " + mid);
    } else {
        // find indexes of min and max elements
        int minId = 0;
        int maxId = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < o.size(); i++) {
            int val = o.get(i);
            if (val < o.get(minId)) {
                minId = i;
            } else if (val >= o.get(maxId)) {
                maxId = i;
            }
        }

        // sort the indexes
        int tMin = Math.min(minId, maxId);
        int tMax = Math.max(minId, maxId);
        // start removing from bigger index and store the value
        // using `E remove(int index)`
        Integer atMax = o.remove(tMax);
        // System.out.printf("removed o[%d]=%d%n", tMax, atMax);
        Integer atMin = o.remove(tMin);
        // System.out.printf("removed o[%d]=%d%n", tMin, atMin);
        
        removeMidRecursive(o);

        // restore the values by insertig at appropriate index with a correction
        if (tMin > 0) o.add(tMin - 1, atMin); else o.add(0, atMin);
        if (tMax > 0) o.add(tMax - 1, atMax); else o.add(0, atMax);
        
        System.out.println("restored: " + o);
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 5, 1, 1, 7, 6, 7));
System.out.println(arr);
removeMidRecursive(arr);
System.out.println(arr);

System.out.println("------------------");

arr = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(6, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4));
System.out.println(arr);
removeMidRecursive(arr);
System.out.println(arr);
```

output

```
[3, 5, 1, 1, 7, 6, 7]
recursive: [3, 5, 1, 1, 7, 6, 7]
recursive: [3, 5, 1, 7, 6]
recursive: [3, 5, 6]
recursive: [5]
removed mid element: 5
restored: [3, 6]
restored: [3, 1, 7, 6]
restored: [3, 1, 1, 7, 6, 7]
[3, 1, 1, 7, 6, 7]
------------------
[6, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4]
recursive: [6, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4]
recursive: [4, 4, 2, 1, 4]
recursive: [4, 4, 2]
recursive: [4]
removed mid element: 4
restored: [4, 2]
restored: [4, 2, 1, 4]
restored: [6, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4]
[6, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4]
```

---

Recursive removal without keeping the original order is much simpler, and it is using another `List`'s method [`boolean remove(Object item)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-):

```java
public static void removeMidAndShuffle(ArrayList<Integer> o) {
    if (o.size() % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("list size is even, no middle element to remove");
    } else if (o.size() == 1) {
        int mid = o.remove(0);
        System.out.println("removed mid element: " + mid);
    } else {
        Integer min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Integer x : o) {
            min = Math.min(min, x);
            max = Math.max(max, x);
        }
        o.remove(min);
        o.remove(max);
        removeMidAndShuffle(o);
        o.add(min);
        o.add(max);
    }
}
```

Its output:

```
[3, 5, 1, 1, 7, 6, 7]
removed mid element: 5
[3, 6, 1, 7, 1, 7]
---------
[6, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4]
removed mid element: 4
[2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 6]
```

Comment: thank u for this solution but i have to use recursion to solve it

Comment: i tried to make it recursion according to ur solution it worked  removed the middle element but it end up removing all element in the list any idea how i could terminate it i just need it to delete once                                                                   `  if (o.size() ==0 && o.size() % 2 == 0) {

    return;
   }
   else {
    o.remove(o.size() / 2);
    
    System.out.println(o);
  removeMiddle(o);
   
  }}`

Comment: So you need just to find a middle element in the array and remove only this element without using library `sorting`?

Comment: @E00X, you may check the update

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplest case scenario that "iterates" over the values in the ArrayList via recursion.  Note that we have an extra parameter, `i`, that we are passing to track where we are in the list.  This simply removes whatever is in the middle position, based on INDEX.  It does not take into account the values that contained with the list:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(5);

    System.out.println("Before: " + numbers.toString());
    removeMid(numbers, 0);
    System.out.println("After: " + numbers.toString());
  }

  public static void removeMid(ArrayList<Integer> o, int i){
    if (o!=null && o.size()>0) {
      // you didn't give a clear specification for "middle"
      int mid=o.size() / 2; // to the right of middle, for even sized lists 
      if (i == mid) {
        o.remove(i);
      }
      else {
        removeMid(o, i+1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Before: [1, 3, 5]
After: [1, 5]
```